# I want to split a DataFrame into 2 df's using lambda on a column

Tags: pandas, sorting, if-statement, lambda

I got the following pandas DataFrame:

| Value1 | Value2 | Food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 2 | Apple |
| 5 | -5 | Orange |
| -4 | 3 | Peach |
| -2 | 6 | Pineapple |

I'm now trying to split up the rows into 2 Dataframes based on the 'Value1' Value. So that the outcome would look like this:

NegativeValue1:

| Value1 | Value2 | Food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 2 | Apple |
| -4 | 3 | Peach |
| -2 | 6 | Pineapple |

NegativeValue2:

| Value1 | Value2 | Food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -5 | Orange |

I've used a for loop combined with an if statement so far:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
        if data['Value1'].iloc[i] < 0:
            NegativeValue1 = NegativeValue1.append(data.iloc[i])
        else:
            NegativeValue2 = NegativeValue2.append(data.iloc[i])
```

, which does work well, but is too time-intensive for large df's.

Because of this I want to build a lambda function to do this, but I don't have much experience with lambda.

My attempts so far were unsuccessful:

```
NegativeValue1 = NegativeValue1.apply(lambda data:  if data['Value1']  < 0, axis = 1)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
mask = df["Value1"] < 0

print(df[mask])
print("-" * 80)
print(df[~mask])
```

Prints:

```
   Value1  Value2       Food
0      -2       2      Apple
2      -4       3      Peach
3      -2       6  Pineapple
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Value1  Value2    Food
1       5      -5  Orange
```